# How to move a Firestore document between collections using an ElevatedButton in Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Flutter app that uses Firestore as a backend. I have two collections: “Books” and “Read”. I want to create an ElevatedButton that moves a document from the “Books” collection to the “Cart” collection when tapped. I have written some code for the ElevatedButton widget, but it doesn’t work.

this is the code for home.dart which displays the documents from a the collection called Books in a gridview

```
GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 0.4,
            ),
            itemCount: books.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final book = books[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              final author = book['Author'] as String?;
              final genre = book['Genre'] as String?;
              final rating = book['Rating'] as num?;
              final name = book['Name'] as String?;
              final price = book['Price'] as num?;
              final image = book['Image'] as String?;
              final description = book['Description'] as String?;
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BookDetailsPage(
                        author: author,
                        genre: genre,
                        rating: rating,
                        name: name,
                        price: price,
                        image: image,
                        description: description,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 3,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.network(
                            image ?? '',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Text(
                        name ?? 'Unknown Book',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            price != null ? '\$$price' : 'Price = ?',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                            onPressed: () {
                              final bookRef = _firestore
                                  .collection('Books')
                                  .doc(books[index].id);

                              final bookData =
                                  books[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                              _firestore.collection('Wishlist').add(bookData);

                              bookRef.delete();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
```

[image: Image of home.dart]

and this is the code for bookDetails which shows the details of each document in the Books collection when a document from the gridview is clicked

```
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? author, genre, name, image, description;
  final num? price, rating;

  BookDetailsPage({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.image,
    this.description,
    this.author,
    this.genre,
    this.rating,
  });

  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // get the data from the current document
                final bookRef = _firestore.collection('books').doc(name);
                final currentDocData = await bookRef.get();

                if (currentDocData.exists) {
                  // add the document to the Cart collection
                  await _firestore
                      .collection('Cart')
                      .add(currentDocData.data()!);
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Book added to cart'),
                  ));
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Book not found'),
                  ));
                }
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [Text("Add to cart"), Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Picture of bookDetails.dart]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // get a query reference to the document you want to move based on some field value
            final bookQuery = _firestore
                .collection('Books')
                .where('Name', isEqualTo: name);
            // get the query snapshot
            final bookSnapshot = await bookQuery.get();
            // check if the query returned any documents
            if (bookSnapshot.size > 0) {
              // get the first document from the query snapshot
              final bookDoc = bookSnapshot.docs.first;
              // get the data from the document
              final bookData = bookDoc.data();
              // create a new document in the target collection
              await _firestore.collection('Cart').add(bookData);
              // delete the document from the source collection
              await bookDoc.reference.delete();
            } else {
              // handle the case when no document matches the query
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Add to cart"),
                Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_checkout)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
```